# Replace a string in Multiple Files Including Hidden Files?

Tags: bash

On Mac OS X, I tried to replace "string1" in multiple files to "string2". However, there are lots of hidden files such as .filename_hidden

```
grep -rl string1 somedir/ | xargs sed -i 's/string1/string2/g'
```

But here is the error.

```
grep -r apple ./ | xargs sed -i 's/apple/pear/g'
sed: 1: ".//.file2:This": invalid command code .
```

.file2 has

```
This apple is hidden. I still want to replace it to pear
```

I tested it also on Ubuntu:

```
grep -r apple ./ | xargs sed -i 's/${apple}/${pear}/g' ./*.*
sed: can't read ./*.*: No such file or directory
sed: can't read ./.file2:This: No such file or directory
sed: can't read is: No such file or directory
sed: can't read hidden: No such file or directory
sed: can't read apple: No such file or directory
```

**UPDATE:**

Adding the option -l in grep command, Mac OS X terminal gives the following:

```
 ~/bash_play/test_replace $grep -rl apple .
./.file2
./file1

~/bash_play/test_replace $grep -rl apple . | xargs sed -i 's/apple/pear/g'
sed: 1: "./.file2": invalid command code .

 ~/bash_play/test_replace $grep -rl apple . | xargs sed -i 's/apple/pear/g' *

sed: 1: "file1": invalid command code f
 ~/bash_play/test_replace $grep -rl apple . | xargs sed -i 's/apple/pear/g' */*.*
sed: 1: "*/*.*": invalid command code *
```

Comment: You forgot the `-l` option to `grep` in the invocation that produced the error... Examine the output of `grep -r apple ./` before piping it into `xargs ...` - it should be pretty obvious why `xargs` isn't happy about it...

Comment: the issue still exists, please see the updated logs

Comment: `sed -i` on Mac OS X *requires* that you give a backup suffix for your input files, unlike the Linux version where it is optional. Try `... xargs sed -i .bak 's/apple/pear/g'`...

Comment: I can also use ... xargs sed -i '' 's/apple/pear/g'  on Mac OS X to ignore .bak files.